# In-app purchase API Server Error 509

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I get 509's from the server quite a bit.

```
**Server error on InAppRestoreTransactionsRequest: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: HTTP 509 for https://android.clients.google.com/vending/billing/ApiRequest
**
```

Is there a limit to how much you can hit this server in development? My APK is unpublished and the gmail account doing the request is the listed debug account and not the dev/publisher account.

I've waited about two hours and I'm still getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are API Limit calls, or at least server limits.
HTTP Error Code 509 signifies a bandwidth overload. I am inclined to believe this is a general Server problem though, Apache in particular.

> This error occurs when the bandwidth limit imposed by the system administrator has been >reached. The only fix for this issue is to wait until the limit is reset in the following >cycle.
>   Consult the system administrator for information about acquiring more bandwidth.

[Bandwidth Limit Exceeded](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/HTTPCodes#509%20Bandwidth%20Limit%20Exceeded)